# FileNotFoundException; Error

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program where multiple methods can access a file and the array of objects that is read from the file, but I keep getting this error.

```
useHamayelSajaEmployee.java:9: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    public static final Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file); //scanner for reading from file
                                        ^
1 error
```

and this is how the code looks:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class useHamayelSajaEmployee 
{
    public static final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
    public static final HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 
    public static final File file = new File("empList.txt");
    public static final Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file); //scanner for reading from file
```

My professor doesn't allow us to use try-catch. Is there any other way to circumvent this error without using it?

Thank You

Comment: @duffymo,  Make 'em feel bad so they'll never come back.

Comment: When I get done crying I will have a really good comeback.

Answer (score 4):

A little research will tell you: `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception.  You have to wrap that call in a `try/catch` block.

```
public class HamayelSajaEmployee {
    public static final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
    public static final HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 
    public static File file;
    public static Scanner scan2;

    static {
        try {
            file = new File("empList.txt");
            scan2 = new Scanner(file); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Catching a raw `Exception` is also considered bad practice.

Comment: There are no comments in your code. If I was a college professor I would probably give you a zero.

Comment: Will this compile? My compiler complains about: "The blank final field scan2 may not have been initialized"

Comment: Comments are usually nothing more than clutter.  Be wary of any college professor teaching you to program.  Ask them if they've ever had to write code for money.

Comment: @duffymo I am writing this program for an intro to java class and I am not allowed to use any code I haven't taken in class. We never covered try and catch and so I have to solve this issue in a different way

Comment: You cannot solve this without try/catch.  The compiler won't allow you to compile.  A little reading and trying something despite that rigid instruction will help you.  Either you do it or don't hand in a working assignment.  Your choice.

Comment: @duffymo There has to be another way because my professor wouldn't assign it if there wasn't.

Comment: Keep thinking that.  Your professor is wrong; so are you.  When you hand in nothing, and your professor says "I expected students to go beyond what I present", let me know.  It's a black and white choice: You have to handle a checked exception, and that's how you do it.  You either do it or don't have an assignment to hand in.

Comment: @duffymo No, if I hand in something that we haven't learned in class, he will accuse me of cheating and will give me a zero as he has done with students from past years. 8 people got zeroes on their final project last year because of this.

Comment: Your choice.  I don't care.  There's no other way.

Comment: @duffymo Thank you for being so helpful

Comment: I'll wait along with you for someone to tell us how to manage this without a try/catch block.  We'll both learn something.

Comment: Since when is reading ahead and showing initiative "cheating"?  Sounds like you're taking the wrong class from a poor professor.  Don't compound it by being a poor student.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add this

```
try {

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file);

    while (scan2.hasNextLine()) {
        int i = scan2.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    scan2.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

otherwise try

```
catch (Exception e) {
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}
```

Comment: And put the try where....?  I'm guessing the OP has never seen the static block before.

Comment: @Anasbzr My professor doesn't allow us to use try-catch. Is there any other way to circumvent this error without using it?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you don't want to use try-catch then you will have to check if the file is not null then you proceed with your scanner that would work

Comment: My file is not null. I can access it from my main method but not from other mehtods

Comment: I know your file is not null but you will need to make sure you check if the file is not, you need to handle the exception when a file could be null or not found or wrong name ... etc. thats why the exception is there. so if not just state that " file != null

Answer (score 0):

It's because the object "file" may perhaps be null when there is no existing file named "empList.txt".

To fix this, you'd better move the code of Scanner line in to a method rather than a global variable, and add a throw exception to that method:

```
public class useHamayelSajaEmployee {
    public static final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
    public static final HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 
    public static final File file = new File("empList.txt");

    public void methodname() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file); //scanner for reading from file
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a "throws IOException" at the end of the declaration of my main method. Should I do that for all my methods?

Comment: I tried putting a "throws IOException" at the end of one of my method declarations but if I try to call that method anywhere else in the program, I get this error: useHamayelSajaEmployee.java:138: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   listAll();
          ^
1 error

Comment: Doesn't matter how you slice you: The code won't compile or run if you don't handle the checked exception.  WILL NOT.